# Java: How's the loop for reading escaped?

Tags: java, sockets, readline

Going through some tutorials about sockets, I keep coming across code like that:

```
  while(true){ 
    socket.receive(packet); 
    String message = new String(packet.getData(),0,packet.getLength(), TEXT_ENCODING); 
    System.out.println(message); 
  }
```

Question is: How is this loop left? Only via the catch, once receive() is done?

To be more precise, here's what I've done:

```
while(true) {
        try {
            socket.receive(answer);
            resultString = new String(answer.getData(), 0, answer.getLength(), "ASCII");

            if (isMyIdentifier(resultString)) {
                gatewayIP =  answer.getAddress().getHostAddress();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            throw new GatewayNotReachableException();
        }
    }
```

But I keep coming up with a timeoutexception, although the read is correct. So I was wondering, if the exception is the 'expected' way to leave. Although I seriously doubt that... ANd the socket.receive(packet) is, where the exception is thrown.

Comment: You can use a `break` statement: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: There is no `catch` in this code.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen He's not asking how it **can** be done, he's asking how the code (taken from tutorials) works.

Comment: If what @AnthonyGrist says is true, having it in context (by posting where this code came from / the tutorial around it) would be nice

Comment: designed to receive always...

Comment: Well that edit totally changes the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below there is a **continuous** `while loop`, which may seem a suitable implementation, however some servers have a tendency to **keep listening**, and handle the requests simultaneously.

**This while loop will never exit!**

```
while(true){ 
    socket.receive(packet); 
    String message = new String(packet.getData(),0,packet.getLength(), TEXT_ENCODING); 
    System.out.println(message); 
  }
```

Comment: so, if in this case, I actual only expect one answer, receive() would simply wait for the first one to come in and then continue? Meaning, simply removing the loop should do the trick...

Comment: Yes, if you expect only one socket to come in, simply don't loop.

Answer (score 4):

Believe it or not, you don't want all loops to terminate.

One classic example is a web server that has a simple loop that listens for requests, handles the request, then goes back to waiting again - "forever". That's basically what your code example is.

The answer is "this loop is not left", and that's what you want.

Comment: +1, but specifically for the pre-edited question (i.e. the first block of code provided)

Answer (score 0):

The loop is never left, this is the whole purpose of a server staying up.

Or do you want the server to receive one client call and then shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

The loop never gets broken out of unless an error occurs within.

Answer (score 0):

Those two blocks of code imply a very different sense of functionality.

The first one seems to say, "I want my request handler to run indefinitely, until I manually quit the program myself!" Which is a reasonable thing to say.

But the second block of code is quite different. You enter the loop, but will never go around it more than once because either `isMyIdentifier(resultString)` is true, in which case you return out of the method (and the loop of course), or it is not in which case you *still* quit out of the method.  In that case, the loop isn't doing anything at all.

In addition, yes the exception handling provides another way for your second block of code to exit the loop. As for *why* it is throwing an exception, that's another question.

Comment: so, as I thought about one comment above, it would just be right to eliminate the loop altogether?! which in the meantime I've done, which has gotten me rid of the exception.

Comment: I can't imagine the loop alone caused the exception, because in the inner code block the loop isn't doing anything. A return statement exits the entire method, and both branches of your if have a return statement. It never reaches the close `}` of your loop to repeat. I would remove it simply because its code that does nothing, like a return statement after a return statement